# (CM4-Mairiadb) sistema de sincronización a la nube de los datos almacenados

Tags: mariadb, aws, raspbian

Estoy trabajando en un entorno de una CM4 con Raspian, tengo unas tablas dentro de un MariaDB y me justaría hacer algún tipo de sistema que cada día suba los datos recogidos a AWS, así cada día tengo actualizado AWS con una copia de todos los registros que nuevos.

Que me recomendáis que empiece a crear ? Si me recomendáis un programa, not problem lo hago, el tema es que no se que por que linea ir ?

Una sonrisa
Natxo

Comment: Si no tienes más requisitos, tal vez puedas tirar por lo simple y subir los archivos a S3. Organizas el sistema de tal forma que el nombre de la carpeta contenga la marca de tiempo y ya lo tendrías. Tirar por base de datos seguramente te requiera más trabajo y no se si te va a aportar alguna ventaja

Comment: Gracias por el aporte ...